# Listen to a specific scope on angularjs

Tags: angularjs, event-handling, listener

In vanilla JS I can listen to events of a specific DOM element like this: `el.addEventListener('click',function(){});`. Is there an equivalent way to do it with the $on method on angularjs, and listen to a specific scope?

Comment: ngClick exists.   ng-click = "clickHandler()" where clickHandler is a method on $scope.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use my custom triggered events, not just `click`

Comment: ng<Event> exists for a lot of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to listen to a specific scope value, I suggest you use $method service by Angular.

Here is example of how you can use it:

```
scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  scope.counter = scope.counter + 1;
});
```

also:

```
scope.$watch(
  // This function returns the value being watched. It is called for each turn of the $digest loop
  function() { return food; },
  // This is the change listener, called when the value returned from the above function changes
  function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if ( newValue !== oldValue ) {
      // Only increment the counter if the value changed
      scope.foodCounter = scope.foodCounter + 1;
    }
  }
);
```